# How to kill non-responsive GUI task under Unity?

Tags: unity, kill, task-management

I am searching for a newuser-friendly way to kill non-responsive GUI applications under Unity.

I looked over the shoulder of a new Unity user who tried to use gscan2pdf - and gscan2pdf seems to be really broken - after not much tinkering it consumed much CPU und memory, the PC began trashing and the user needed to immediately kill the gscan2pdf GUI which was full-screen, non-responsive and had the focus.

Ok, I know some ways how to do it:

- Hit `Alt+F2` and type `xkill` -> select the window
- Hit `Alt+F2` start `xterm`, use `top` or `pgrep` and then `kill PID` or directly use `pkill`

Both are ways which are not very intuitive for GUI centric users.

Is there some Unity shortcut to get something like `xkill`?

Or is the best GUI-way to add a top-like GUI to the Unity-starter? And which one?

Comment: You could define a shortcut keybinding for `xkill`..

Comment: @nitstorm, ok, post how to do it as answer and I'll up-vote it.

Comment: Posted with screenshots.

Comment: I didn't even know about the xkill thing...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could create a keyboard shortcut for `xkill`.

1. Type keyboard in the Unity Dash and click the icon. Select the
   shortcuts tab.
2. There, scroll down to the **custom shortcuts** section and click on the
   `+` button
3. Now name your shortcut something and let the command be `xkill` and then click ok.
4. Finally click on the `xkill` shortcut and press the desired key-combo to assign a shortcut to it and that's it :)
5. Pressing the keyboard shortcut will activate `xkill` whenever you need it.

[image: keyboard_shortcuts]

[image: keyboard_shortcuts2]

Comment: An addition: To cancel an `xkill`, just right click anywhere and the cursor will change from a cross to the default arrow.

Answer (score 6):

The best way I find is using terminal window :

goto terminal :

```
sudo ps -aux | grep "name of application"
```

note down the process ID

```
sudo kill -9 "processID"
```

since, If GUI application becomes unresponsive, for time-being it slows down the X(GUI) and all actions would be slowed down, so any gui action for closing the process will be slow.

Comment: The OP doesn't want the `kill` command, he has specifically stated so in the second bulleted point.

Comment: Wow, this is bad advice on several different levels - 1. I asked for a GUI or GUI-relatic solution for killing a task 2. `ps ... | grep` - there is the command `pgrep`, which is also mentioned in the question 3. `kill -9` sends `SIGKILL` under which the program has no chance to terminate in a gracious way - usually one should always try `kill PID` first - this sends `SIGTERM` - only if the process does not terminate on `SIGTERM`, one should issue a `kill -9 PID`

Comment: Also, I returns too many numbers. I don't think novices will easily find the PID without help.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do is to run System Monitor.  You can select a process with the mouse and hit the "End Process" button to kill it.  This should even work with unresponsive processes but I don't think it is as strong as kill -9.  It does have the advantage that it is a totally GUI solution and is very similar to the analogous Activity Monitor in Mac OS X.  That's helpful to those of us who move back and forth between Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try it by myself, but [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/force-quit-applet-unity-launcher/) small script looks useful. It adds a "Force quit" option to the unity launcher.

Answer (score 1):

[Script to send SIGTERM to the currently active window](https://github.com/l0b0/xkillthis) based on a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77384/3645).