# How to restart x window (xorg?) when it's dead

Tags: xorg

I found my x window is dead, all the graphic application have no reaction on the mouse click,so i have to change to the tty1 to work,use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but the previous work is still need to rework.

The command `ps` doesn't display the xorg's thread, so I couldn't kill it.

And when I need to go back to graphic window, I must reboot the system.

Answer (score 7):

From tty1 you can use the following command to restart only the GUI, without rebooting the system:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```

Another useful command in this case can be:

```bsh
xkill  # or xkill -all
```

(See `man xkill` to get to know how it works) and you can [create a keyboard shortcut for `xkill`](https://askubuntu.com/q/90773/147044) so you don't need to go in tty1 to use it.

Comment: Should be `sudo service` not `sudo services`. :-)

Comment: Failed to restart lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not found.

Comment: I think the command in my case is `systemctl restart display-manager` but alas it didn't help get my screen back.